# Does MongoDB C++ driver compiled with authentication options penalize clients not using authentication?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

Mongo C++ driver has two compilation option. From [driver documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/legacy-v1/installation/#scons-options-when-compiling-the-c-driver):

> - `--ssl` Enables SSL support. You will need a compatible version of the SSL libraries available.The default authorization mechanism since MongoDB version 3.0 is SCRAM-SHA-1. If you want to use standard MongoDB authentication, you should compile with –ssl option for SCRAM-SHA-1 mechanism support.
> - `--use-sasl-client` Enables SASL, which MongoDB uses for the Kerberos authentication available on MongoDB Enterprise. You will need a compatible version of the SASL implementation libraries available. The Cyrus SASL libraries are what we test with, and are recommended.

I wonder about clients not using authentication (which is a typical scenario in which the CB-MongoDB connection is secured using other means, e.g. level 3 firewalling, or simply the user doesn't want it, for whatever reason) from the point of view of performance. I mean, it is fine that users wanting authentication pay a price for it (in terms of performance penalty of the SSL CB-MongoDB communication needed to authentication) but users not wanting authentication shouldn't be affected .

Is the driver clever enough so even having being compiled using `--ssl` and `--use-sasl-client` clients not using authentication gets the same performance than if the driver would have been compiled without these options?

*Note:* I know this is question about Mongo C++ legacy driver which is a legacy piece of software. However, maybe a similar one applies also to the new driver (assuming it has a similar option-based compilation configurability) so I understand that the question is meaningfull anyway.

Comment: Authentication is tightly coupled with role based access control https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authorization/ which can hardly be achieved by "other means".

Comment: @AlexBlex thanks for the feedback! I have edited to add the text "or simply the user doesn't want it, for whatever reason" to take your comment into account.